# 1 ISP 2 wifi routers LAN-LAN dropping

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, lan

I need some guidance.
I have 1 ISP fiber gateway and 2 routers (R1 LAN to R2).

```
R1 192.168.10.1 DHCP 50-199 WIFI SSID ABC CH1
R2 192.168.11.1 DHCP DESABLED WIFI SSID ABC CH11
```

R2 is dropping internet frequently.

Note:R2 in bridge mode.

Is there any thing wrong with this config ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I did this by running an Ethernet cable in a conduit inside a hall closet. Now I have Ethernet upstairs and put in an Access Point. Works great.

Comment: i did the same, ethernet to upstairs, but even access point keep dropping signal .i dont know is it the IP DHCP range or the r2 has to be different ip

Comment: Make sure:  The Ethernet works by itself;  The subnet upstairs is the same downstairs. That should help

Comment: ethernet is good, you mean R1 192.168.10.1 and R2 192.168.10.2

Comment: Your subnet is the same and fine. If Ethernet is working, see if you can try a different Access Point.

Comment: R1 192.168.10.1 and R2 192.168.10.2  OR   R1 192.168.10.1 and R2 192.168.11.1

Comment: The first pair (... 10.1 and ...  10.2) are the same subnet.  The second pair (..... 10.1 and ....  11.1) are different subnets.  Correct the latter to .... 10.3 or like and test again

Comment: R2 can't be connected LAN-to-LAN to R1 if their IPs `192.168.x` don't have the same `x`.

Comment: thanks alot.  it is working now both lan connected same subnet a.a.a.1 a.a.a.2.  i will monitor further,

Comment: wifi name should be the same on both R1.R2 but diff ch   right?

Comment: Channel is not related to subnet but to reception and possible interference.  Channel needs operational testing.  Since I have you going, I will post an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run an Ethernet connection to your target location. You said you did this.

Make sure the Ethernet works by itself.

Make sure the subnet upstairs is the same downstairs. That will help.

The first pair (router) (... 10.1 and ... 10.2) are the same subnet. The second pair (..... 10.1 and .... 11.1) are different subnets. Correct the latter to .... 10.3 or like and test again.

You note that upon changing, all is working so this has helped you.

Channel is not related to subnet but to reception and possible interference. Channel needs operational testing.

Overall, this appears to have answered your needs.

Comment: thanks John. That was a very quick guidance. it took me hours of trials.

Comment: It worked for one day then . My 2nd router assign a different Ip 260.xxx.xxx.xxx for my phone which is not even the static ip.(and no internet)  Is this an ip conflict? Or my router is not working correctly ?

Comment: Your internal IP is 192.168.x.y.  192.168 is a very standard internal IP address. You second router is now 260.x.y.z which is certainly not on the same subnet as the first. Also 260.x.y.z is not part of the non-routable IP addresses for internal use (10.x.x.x, 172.16.x.x and 192.168.x.x).   Either something went wrong with the router or its settings got messed up.

Comment: Well ,following restart and unplugging and replugging the lan cable it works normal.  With the correct ip,  it seems that when ever i use a vpn on my phone or connect to 5G mobile data. And connect back to wifi it gets messed up.

Comment: Check your VPN provider to see if that is the issue. I have used Commercial VPN and also a HUAWEI cellular router when my main ISP goes out, and my 2 routers (connected like yours, remain very stable.

Comment: after a lot of trials, it seems that after certain number of users connected to my 2nd router ,,it stops assigning ip to other devices, only after reset.                  is it because the DHCP range i set for the first router/? while trying to connect through my pc it only connect to network but no internet "cannot configure ip msg"  and while trying from my phone "network is connected but not internet and different ip from my both routers 169.254.220.xxx"

Comment: R1 is netgear ORBI R50       R2 is Huawei HG659 both connected LAN cable through LAN port        should my R2 static IP be outside the R2 DHCP

Comment: What would happen to my MOBILE IP when i move between the 2 wifi network. Since the phone ip was given by one router!   Some conflict is happening either by moving devices between the 2 wifi network which i canot figuer out

Comment: Devices should not cause Routers to reset.  You know from earlier that a properly set up router will work. Maybe consider a new router.